# Why my light meter's values are blank on Arduino Serial Monitor?

Tags: serial, sensors

I tried to represent the values of TSL 2591 Adafruit light sensor on my Arduino Serial Monitor, but for some reason, I could not do that. The Arduino Serial Monitor just enters some blank values and scrolls down. 
Here is the code:

```c++
uint16_t x = tsl.getLuminosity(TSL2591_VISIBLE);
y = float(tsl.getLuminosity(TSL2591_VISIBLE));
z = (y, DEC);
Serial.write((byte)z);
```

`x`, `y`, and `z` are floats initially.

Comment: Did you enabled the serial communication on arduino by using `Serial.begin(9600)`?

Comment: What's `z = (y, DEC);` supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, I enabled it. What if I change 9600 to another value? @svtag

Comment: I think it converts the values to decimals @Gerben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Serial.println(x); to print a number as text. Function write() sends the raw byte and Serial Monitor shows the character with that ASCII code, which is not valid or a not visible control character.

---

For the `z = (y, DEC);` from Wikipedia:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

so `z` is always 10 (value of constant DEC), which is ASCII code for the new line character

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85853/discussion-on-answer-by-juraj-why-my-light-meters-values-are-blank-on-arduino-s).